# How does Twilio verify an apps identity?

Tags: android, ios, api, security, twilio

Twilio's documentation says the following

> For the security of your Twilio account, you should not embed a Capability Token or your Twilio Auth Token as strings in the app you submit to the App Store.

And

> The Twilio Client SDK uses a capability token to sign communications from your iOS app to Twilio. These tokens are created by you on your server and allow you to specify what capabilities are going to be available to your app, such as whether it can receive incoming connections, make outgoing connections, etc. These tokens always have an expiration, which means all tokens have a limited lifetime to protect you from abuse. It is up to you to determine how often these tokens must be refreshed.

My question is, how does Twilio verify the authenticity of the app if you can't embed a token in the app? You might be able to make a token invalid, but what keeps an abuser from requesting a new token? If you have an app with 100k + users it will be impossible to manage.

Comment: Even though abuse could request a new token you're not giving it out easily...

Comment: You kind of are right? Because why would you deny a token request from an app that is supposedly legit.

Comment: I think if the token is hard-coded it can be abused and when you invalidate that - what would happen to everyone else who uses the same token? On the other hand, when you create a logic of authenticating each device/request before giving it a token you can always disable the abuser, invalidate token, and give a new token to other people (who'd request a new one).

Comment: What would that logic of authenticating be? Because I am thinking what keeps the abuser from requesting a new token? Say you're using Twilio to send an OTP sms during on boarding, that person won't be registered anywhere.